# apt-get update: How to check for GPG errors when using scripts?

Tags: bash, debian, apt, gpg, verification

When running.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

For example something like this could happen.

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.torproject.org wheezy Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1409325681 KEYEXPIRED 1409325681 KEYEXPIRED 1409325681 KEYEXPIRED 1409325681
```

(This question is not about this particular example warning. It has already been [reported](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12994).)

Exit code.

```
echo $?
0
```

Exit code 0 is problematic for automated use in scripts, where success is expected.

This is a bug in Debian's apt-get: 
[apt: Provide meaningful exit codes for gpg failures](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=745735)

How to notice GPG errors in scripts when the exit code is not reliable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a wrapper script around `/usr/bin/gpgv`. Supply the pathname to the wrapper script as the value of `Dir::Bin::gpg` (using `apt-get --option`). Have the wrapper script examine the output and exit status of `gpgv`, and communicate failure back to the toplevel script somehow (I suggest using `kill` to send a signal).

Comment: I'm really a noob at bash scripting, could you give me an example on that?